# crystal reports show the field on specific position

Tags: position, field, move, crystal-reports-2008

Below is sample of my report when customer have xyz things bought then the param1 n param2 shows on proper place of bill when customer buy more than 5.or 6 things or less than 3 then param 1 n param2 not shows on proper place because tax. N old balance tag are pre written on bill that's y param1.N 2 . Must not move how to fix it thx..
..

```
Header. --------------------.

Seller name.              Textobj
Date.                             Dateobj

Detail  ................
2  sugar jar 50.        100$
4. Peanuts 10.          40$
X
Y
X
A
B
C
.: ..,. .......,   . . . .... .... ...............
                                    140$  



Total tax = param1
Old balance=paRam2
, .:    .. .... ,........ .........................
```

Comment: couldn't able to understand..can you explain more?

Comment: please check the link

Comment: http://i58.tinypic.com/4qmzqw.jpg

Answer (score 0):

ok solution for this is to place the param1, param2 etc in page footer not in details

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to show the field on specific position and it is missing, look at the pic and I hope this helps... Click this drop down, you will locate also edit and also delete your lost field and parameters

[image: Click this drop down will help you]